# Using a FactoryGirl object id in another field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

```
factory :foo do
  bar # want this to use foo's id in calculating bar's value

  # current solution
  # ugly because it requires an extra save
  after_create { |foo| foo.bar = foo.id; foo.save! }

  # tried this too but foo.id is still nil at this point
  # after_build { |foo| foo.bar = foo.id } 
end
```

Is there a better way to work with the object's id during object creation? This has come up in the scenario outlined above.

It has also come up in another scenario where foo has an ActiveRecord before_create_callback which uses foo.id. With AR, the object has an id when the callback is called and the method does as expected. With FG, the object does not have an id when the callback is called and therefore the method does not behave as expected. Again, I resort to after_create with an extra explicit save.

Any suggestions/tips to working with object id's during FactoryGirl object creation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full example that works outside of rails in irb.  You have to have the proper gems installed however.

Create the tables in sqlite:

```
sqlite3 /tmp/development.db
> create table foos ( id int, name varchar(50), primary key(id));
> create table bars ( id int, name varchar(50), foo_id int, primary key(id));
```

Note that this is factory_girl 3.x syntax.

```
require 'factory_girl'
require 'active_record'
require 'active_support'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter => 'sqlite3', :database => '/tmp/development.db'
)

class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id, :name
  has_one :bar
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id, :name
  belongs_to :foo
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :foo do
    sequence :id do |n|
      n
    end
    name "Foo Name" # use Faker
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :bar do
    sequence(:id) {|n| n }
    association :foo, :factory => :foo
    name "Bar Name" # use Faker
  end
end

bar = FactoryGirl.build(:bar)
puts bar.inspect
# => #<Bar id: 1, name: "Bar Name", foo_id: 1>
```

You'll notice that you can only run this once because we don't rollback our tables after this runs.  That's because factory_girl figured out an association is needed and wrote the records to the DB even though all we did is a `build` call.  Normally `build` doesn't write to the DB.  You can rollback manually:

```
> delete from foos;
> delete from bars;
```

Sorry for the very un-railsy example but at least you can play with this on the side without messing with your project.